# Viewing records in a Row in a column from the same Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am crating a view to display records with contract dates in them.

The data for this view comes from two tables, one which stores the client details and another which stores the date info.

The dates themeselves are stored in the DateCol column and the ID for the DateCol column comes from TypeID eg 118 equals a Contract Start Date and 119 equals an End date.
This returns about 250 results.

The view I have built runs a lookup against the client id and shows the date from the date_type(ie 118 and 119 shows 01/01/2012 and 01/03/2012). If I add a third column that shows me 120, the total number of results is reduced to 6.

I need to see all the results but im not sure how to build a view that shows all of these. I cant modify the original database as it is a backed for Maximizer.

We are using SQL 2005 and I have built this using the Management STudio but my knowledge is a bit limited.

This is the code for my view:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl 
       INNER JOIN dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_118 
         ON dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Client_Id = 
            dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_118.Client_Id 
       INNER JOIN dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_119 
         ON dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Client_Id = 
            dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_119.Client_Id 
       INNER JOIN dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_120 
         ON dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Client_Id = 
            dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_120.Client_Id 
       INNER JOIN dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_121 
         ON dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Client_Id = 
            dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_121.Client_Id 
WHERE  ( dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Record_Type = '1' ) AND ( dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Name_Type = 'C' ) 
OR ( dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Record_Type = '1' ) AND ( dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Name_Type = 'C' )
```

Comment: You are probably using some `INNER JOIN` when you need an `OUTER JOIN`, but its hard to say whithout looking at your code (so, please, post the code for your view)

Comment: Select * FROM         dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl INNER JOIN
                      dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_118 ON dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Client_Id = dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_118.Client_Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_119 ON dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Client_Id = dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_119.Client_Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_120 ON dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Client_Id = dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_120.Client_Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_121 ON dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Client_Id = dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_121.Client_Id

Comment: WHERE     (dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Record_Type = '1') AND (dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Name_Type = 'C') OR
                      (dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Record_Type = '1') AND (dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Name_Type = 'C')

Comment: I can see the INNER JOIN's that you are refering to but I am sunre how to convert them

Comment: Please, add the code you just posted to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, First of all you should list the actual column names that you need on your view and not use `*`. I believe that you just need to change the `INNER JOIN`s for `LEFT JOIN`s. So it would be like this:

```
SELECT [List Your Columns Here]
FROM   dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_118 
         ON dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Client_Id = 
            dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_118.Client_Id 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_119 
         ON dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Client_Id = 
            dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_119.Client_Id 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_120 
         ON dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Client_Id = 
            dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_120.Client_Id 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_121 
         ON dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Client_Id = 
            dbo.FOOTPRINTS_Companies_121.Client_Id 
WHERE  ( dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Record_Type = '1' ) AND ( dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Name_Type = 'C' ) 
OR ( dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Record_Type = '1' ) AND ( dbo.AMGR_Client_Tbl.Name_Type = 'C' )
```

Also, you should note that on your `WHERE` there seems to be a duplicated condition.

Comment: Lamak, After I modified the above code with LEFT JOIN rather than INNERJOIN, it worked PERFECTLY! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Raddo2003 - Oops, sorry about that, I modified my answer anyway :-)